# I designed a poster for non profit, but I don't have license for the fonts. Is it ok?

Tags: font-licensing

I went to a design school but they never told me to buy any fonts/typefaces. I think the fonts/typefaces were actually given to the students to use for projects. I probably have more than 80+ different type of fonts to use in my computer.

I recently did a poster for a non-profit, with the fonts/typefaces that were given to me from school. I didn't charge them anything.

My question are:

1. Is it legal for me to do that since I don't have license for those font/typeface? (Univers, Rockwell, Berkeley)
2. If the not profit have the ability to print unlimited, do they need to pay for the font?
3. How do i find out if the font/typeface is free to use anywhere?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

> Is it legal for me to do that since I don't have license for those font/typeface? (Univers, Rockwell, Berkeley)

Depends on the license. Assuming the school properly licensed them in the first place, they were likely 'for student use only' licenses.

> If the not profit have the ability to print unlimited, do they need to pay for the font?

They need to pay for a license of the font if they are using it as a font (meaning you didn't convert the text to outlines before you gave them the file).

> How do i find out if the font/typeface is free to use anywhere?

Read the license file that you should have gotten with the fonts.

FWIW, the fact that your client is a non-profit and you didn't charge them for the work really has no bearing on this. It's still considered commercial usage so you need to have typefaces that allow commercial use in their licenses.

Comment: @Gunawanhere you are welcome!